# Python: Need the result of functools.partial(function) to be known as something else

Tags: python, maya

My software supports python to automate tasks (Maya). When I undo or redo in this software it prints the last command, unfortunately for Python this is the memory address of the function rather than something actually useful. So the user sees the output `Undo: <functools.partial object at 0x000002235DEDDF48>` instead of something actually useful like `Undo: Set Key on something at frame x`

There appears to be no option to make Maya print a useful result from within it's own functionality, so now I want to ask if there's some obscure way cheese it with python to have that instance call itself something useful in a way the software will print while hopefully not interfering with the functionality. I'll try anything at this point!

```
def testFunc():
    pass

test = partial(testFunc)
```

test results in `<functools.partial object at 0x000002235DEA95E8>`

If anyone can think of a more accurate title please edit / suggest.

Comment: What specifically does it print? The value of the last expression? Some specific variable?

Comment: You can define a `partial` subclass that prints a nicer identification by defining `__repr__()`. Where it will get that identification, though?

Comment: @kindall that was the correct answer, or led me to it. If I subclass partial I can  `def __repr__(self): return result` and to answer your question it gets that identification from `def __init__(self, *args):` called prior to `__repr__()`, and takes it from `self.result = args[-1]` so if I call `mypartial(function, arg1, arg2, arg3, extraarg4)` then extraarg4 becomes that identification.

Comment: @Vii glad that worked out! Maybe post your code as an answer to help future visitors.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to kindall giving me a lead in the comments I was able to find an answer. Subclassing `partial` and defining `__repr__()` is the key.

By grabbing the `*args` on `__init__()` and storing it as `self.result` we  can use it on `__repr__()` to return the last argument given to `*args` as the result given by Maya when using Undo/Redo.

```
class rpartial(partial):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.result = args[-1]
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.result

rpartial(function, arg1, arg2, undoredo)
```

The string given to rpartial on the last line for `undoredo` is what will be printed by Maya when using Undo/Redo.